# Portable POS System POS Model: TC-TOUCH-T2 Flutter

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, arabic, pos, arabic-support

I have this Portable POS System POS Model: TC-TOUCH-T2
I am writing program in flutter any one know how to connect the in-build printer to Flutter to print a invoice?

Thanks
Ace

Answer (score 0):

Try out `esc_pos_printer` package, you can find it [here](https://pub.dev/packages/esc_pos_printer) (it's network printer)
You can use `blue_thermal_printer` for bluetooth connection, check [here](https://pub.dev/packages/blue_thermal_printer)

Or you can find more useful packages in [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/flutter/packages?q=printer) you can choose suitable one for your requirement.

Hope it might help

Comment: thanks you but this is Bluetooth connection not WiFi connection

Comment: I use blue_thermal_printer for bluetooth connection, it is not working with arabic, it is not working give me unknown characters any help?

Answer (score 0):

Use [esc_pos_printer](https://github.com/andrey-ushakov/esc_pos_printer) for a network printer (LAN/WiFi) or [esc_pos_bluetooth](https://github.com/andrey-ushakov/esc_pos_bluetooth) for a Bluetooth printer. Both packages use [esc_pos_utils](https://github.com/andrey-ushakov/esc_pos_utils) under the hood.